# Timer doesn't stop at green color

Tags: mit-scratch

I'm making a basic labyrinth game in scratch 2 and I can't work out why the timer isn't stopping when I clearly programmed it to stop when touching color green.

These are the code blocks
[image]

Comment: You should provide some explanation of what is triggering the error condition. A link to the code would help.

Comment: How careful have you been in selecting __exactly__ the same color in the target image and in the 'touches' block? Is the target image maybe less than two pixels in width, potentially causing it to blend with the background?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a `Green Line` make a new `sprint` with a straight line with green line and use this code
[image: code sprinter]